# Tangent to cos(x+y) =y

Tags: tangent-line

Find all the tangents to the curve $y = \cos(x + y),x$ which belongs to $[-\pi$,$\pi]$, that are parallel to the line $x + 2y = 0$.

I differentiate it and equate to $(-1/2)$.

$$y' = -\sin(x+y)[1+y']$$

And I get $[\sin(x+y)]/[1+\sin(x+y)]= (1/2)$.

But then how to find the tangent?

Comment: By differentiating the curve @5xum

Comment: @5xum edited the question

Comment: What you did so far is right. But, you know $y'=-\frac12$. Why do you resolve for $y'$ and not for $\sin(x+y)$. If you know the value for $\sin(x+y)$ you can consider all the angles that give that value and simultaneously fulfill the original equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can proceed continuously after that step. We have got the slope of tangent at $(x,y) = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{-\sin(x+y)}{ 1+\sin(x+y)}$.

Since tangents to the given curve are parallel to $x +2y =0$ which has a slope of $-\frac{1}{2}$, we can get $$\sin(x +y) =1$$ $$\Rightarrow x+y = n\pi +(-1)^n\frac{\pi}{2} , n\in \mathbb Z$$ Then $y =0$ for all $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Since, $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$, we get $x =\frac{\pi}{2}$. Thus, tangents to the given curve are parallel to $x+2y =0$ only at $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$ for $-\pi \leq x \leq \pi$. Now, I leave it to you to find the tangent at $(\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)$. Hope it helps.

Comment: $$\sin(u)=1\implies u=2m\pi+\dfrac\pi2$$ where $m$ is any integer. But why $y=0$?

Comment: The answer given as are  x+2y = $\pi$/2 and x+2y=-3$\pi$/2

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Sir, we have $ y =\cos(x +y) = \cos( n\pi + (-1)^n \frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$. Sir, if $(x +y) =2m\pi +\frac{\pi}{2}$, even then y=0.

Comment: @user123733 The other equation is got, I.e., x+2y =-3$\pi$/2 is got when $x = -\frac{3\pi}{2}$ But it is not in our permissible range.

Comment: So there can be infinte tangents

Comment: Yes, for every value of n, there is an x, so there are infinite tangents. Correct. That is why we limit ourselves to a range.